# What is the purpose of escaping these characters? [From Javascript & JQuery book]

Tags: javascript, escaping

From the Events chapter in the JavaScript and jQuery book by Jon Duckett.

Here's the code:

```
var msg = '<div class=\"header\"><a id=\"close\" href="#">close X</a></div>';
msg += '<div><h2>System Maintenance</h2>';
msg += 'Our servers are being updated between 3 and 4 a.m. ';
msg += 'During this time, there may be minor disruptions to service.</div>';

var elNote = document.createElement('div');       
elNote.setAttribute('id', 'note');                
elNote.innerHTML = msg;                           
document.body.appendChild(elNote);               

function dismissNote() {                      
  document.body.removeChild(elNote);              
}

var elClose = document.getElementById('close');  
elClose.addEventListener('click', dismissNote, false);
```

I'm just interested in the beginning bit. Why is `\"header\"` and `\"close\"` escaped, while `href="#"` isn't? I ran the code without escaping, and it still works.

Comment: This looks like a mistake. I guess in the first draft the whole string was enclosed in double quotes, later replaced with single ones, but omitting to remove the backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to teach you to use escape quotes because if you wrote the code:

```
var msg = "<div class=\"header\"><a id=\"close\" href="\#">close X</a></div>";
```

This should work, but if the quotes weren't escaped, it wouldn't work. The single quotes says that everything inside it is an exact quote, ie. quotes (") are interpreted as a string, not as a start (or end) of a new string.

This code does not work:

```
var msg = "<div class="header"><a id="close" href="#">close X</a></div>";
```

Comment: Except that in this case, escaping is useless, so even for teaching purposes, it's kind of confusing to show escaping where none are needed.